# how to send integer value from php file to android activity using json?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I need to send the integer value from PHP file to android activity, but it is showing exception error.

That is,

> Exception value [",null,null] at user_data of the type
>   org.json.JSONARRAY cannot be converted to JSONObject.

Anyone help me please.

This is my output with error.

[image: This is my output with error]

My PHP code which will fetch the date from database and separate into separate day, month, year. Here the process is working fine, but not able to send that day, month, year, to android activity.

```
       <?php 
error_reporting(0);
require "init.php";

 //$name = $_POST["name"];
 //$password = $_POST["password"];


 $name = "surya";
 $password = "1995";









$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user_info` WHERE `name`='".$name."' AND `password`='".$password."';";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$retrive = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){




   $user_id =  $row['id'];


    $ids=$row;
     $q = "SELECT `ScheduleDate` FROM user_info WHERE id ='" . $user_id . "'";


        $result = $con->query($q);
        $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
          $date=$rows["ScheduleDate"];


 list($year,$month,$day) = split("-",$date);

 $response = array( $year , $month ,$day );

  //echo $year;
   //echo $month;
   //echo $day;


//$response = array("year"=>"$year","month"=>"$month","day"=>"$day");



}

//if(!$response==null)
 // {

    //  echo "Matches";

 // }
  //else
  //{
      // echo "No match";
  //}

 echo json_encode(array("user_data"=> $response));


?>
```

This my database structure.

[image: This my database structure]

Full Android code Main activity,home Activity

Main activity

```
      package com.example.text;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name, password;
    String Name, Password;
    Context ctx=this;

    String year,month,day;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_name);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_password);
    }

    public void main_register(View v){
        //startActivity(new Intent(this,Register.class));
    }

    public void main_login(View v){
        Name = name.getText().toString();
        Password = password.getText().toString();
        BackGround b = new BackGround();
        b.execute(Name, Password);
    }

    class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String name = params[0];
            String password = params[1];
            String data="";
            int tmp;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.powersys-india.com/sample/loo/login.php");
                String urlParams = "name="+name+"&password="+password;

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();

                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                while((tmp=is.read())!=-1){
                    data+= (char)tmp;
                }

                is.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return data;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            String err=null;
            try {

               /* if(s.equals("Matches")) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "has a value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                if(s.equals("No match")) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }*/


                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("user_data");  //Parse array from json object



                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject curr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                      year = curr.getString("year");
                      month = curr.getString("year");
                      day = curr.getString("day");

                    //Do stuff with the month day String here
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Home.class);
            i.putExtra("year", year);
            i.putExtra("month", month);
            i.putExtra("day", day);
            i.putExtra("err", err);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }
```

}

Home Avtivity

```
 package com.example.text;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    String day, month, year, Err;
    TextView nameTV, emailTV, passwordTV, err;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        nameTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_name);
        emailTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_email);
        passwordTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_password);
        err = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.err);

        year = getIntent().getStringExtra("year");
        month = getIntent().getStringExtra("month");
        day = getIntent().getStringExtra("day");
        Err = getIntent().getStringExtra("err");





        nameTV.setText("YEAR "+year);
        passwordTV.setText("MONTH "+month);
        emailTV.setText("DATE "+day);
        err.setText(Err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check in the response of the API call is ti JsonArray or jsonObject?

Comment: Can you show your JSON that you'll getting from server end

Comment: Harsh,sir, i didnt understand

Comment: Show your JSON format which you are getting?

Comment: @selvas check my answer.Because your sending JSON Array from PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Php file, you're sending the response as `JsonArray`.So convert response string to `JSONArray` and Parse

Use

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("user_data");  //Parse array from json object

for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
 {
 JSONObject curr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

 String year = curr.getString("year")


 //Do stuff with the month day String here
 }
```

Instead

```
 JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
 JSONObject user_data = root.getJSONObject("user_data");
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161609/discussion-on-answer-by-r2r-how-to-send-integer-value-from-php-file-to-android-a).

Comment: sir can you tell me,what is wrong? when i use the id, to fetched the ScheduleDate from the database it is working,i checked it using the echo ,so i splited the date using list($year,$month,$day) = split("-",$date);
and i put them in echo seperately for year month and date it is working,and so i put them in   echo json_encode(array("user_data"=> $response));

 i think ,here is the problem in sending the splited date to android,or in receving it in android
in android activity i checked the year day and month using toast it shows nothing.

Comment: I will tell you how to fix  this in php side..Dont split the date  using list($year,$month,$day) = split("-",$date); .Just send in php script  side  like this {
  "user_data": [
    {
      "date": "2017-12-07"
    }
  ]
}  ...Mobile side we can parse that easily

Comment: Because you have to send valid json like this {
  "user_data": [
    {
      "date": "2017-12-07"
    }

  ]
}